# What IP's are in this IP block and how to use them?

Tags: centos, ip, subnet

I am very new to this IP block thing so please excuse any "nooby" mistakes.

I just purchased a dedicated server and in my control panel it says:

> IPv4 Assignment #1: 192.151.150.194/29

Does this mean the following IP addresses are usable?

- 192.151.150.193
- 192.151.150.194
- 192.151.150.195
- 192.151.150.196
- 192.151.150.197
- 192.151.150.198

If the IP's listed above are correct, do I have to enable them to use them?

Thanks,
Faraaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes, and yes.

Basically, the `/29` syntax means that 29 of the 32 bits are to be used for the netmask, leaving you with only 3 bits to use for addresses. This gives you 6 addresses to use, but two of those are typically reserved (one for broadcast, one for loopback).

So yes, the addresses you listed are available, and yes, you'd have to enable them to use them.

Also, the following will be helpful to you: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php

Comment: Thanks for the help.